# Child inside parent with min-height: 100% not inheriting height

Tags: css, html

I found a way to make a div container to occupy at least full height of a page, by setting `min-height: 100%;`. However, when I add a nested div and set `height: 100%;`, it doesn't stretch to container's height. Is there a way to fix it?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#containment {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

#containment-shadow-left {
  height: 100%;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="containment">
  <div id="containment-shadow-left">
    Hello World!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Modern day solution: give the container `display:flex` and `flex-direction:column` and give the child `flex:1`.

Comment: @jackocnr That doesn't work in any IE due to a [bug](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3), it was fixed in Edge.

Comment: @jackocnr not working in chrome or firefox in 2021, but it works in some online code editors

Answer (score 196, accepted):

This is a reported webkit (chrome/safari) bug, children of parents with min-height can't inherit the height property: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26559

Apparently Firefox is affected too (can't test in IE at the moment)

Possible workaround:

- add position:relative to #containment
- add position:absolute to #containment-shadow-left

The bug doesn't show when the inner element has absolute positioning.

See http://jsfiddle.net/xrebB/

**Edit on April 10, 2014**

Since I'm currently working on a project for which I *really* need parent containers with `min-height`, and child elements inheriting the height of the container, I did some more research.

**First:** I'm not so sure anymore whether the current browser behaviour really is a bug. CSS2.1 specs say:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto'.

If I put a min-height on my container, I'm not *explicitly* specifying its height - so my element should get an `auto` height. And that's exactly what Webkit - and all other browsers - do.

**Second, the workaround I found:**

If I set my container element to `display:table` with `height:inherit` it acts exactly the same way as if I'd give it a `min-height` of 100%. And - more importantly - if I set the child element to `display:table-cell` it will perfectly inherit the height of the container element - whether it's 100% or more.

Full CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  background: green;
  display: table;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  background: red;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

The markup:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
      <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/xrebB/54/.

Comment: Although this is a good solution, I like most the one from @Kushagra Gour, because that does not affect the layout (I don't want to use table diplays...)

Comment: Its a strange reading of the spec to conclude that min-/max-height isn't explicit...and by strange I mean wrong. Reading the whole paragraph, in context, this interpretation is incorrect. 

To clarify why, "height of the containing block," in context, is semantically different then the height property. If instead, the phrasing was "height *property* of the containing block" then Your interpretation would make sense (and be a bug in the spec).

Comment: position: absolute;
min-height: inherit;
min-width: inherit;
This worked for me

Comment: Note, as the edit (and the bugs.webkit link) mentions, this isn't really a bug — if a parent was `min-height: 20px`, but a child was `height: 120%`, that would influence the parent's height, which would influence the child's height... When the parents height is unknowable, the children can't use it for sizing.

Comment: What's actually so bad about setting the position of the child as absolute? Sure, its a hack but you don't need a clearfix bc of the containing element and since you specify the height of the absolutely positioned child explicitly it passes on its height to its children quite well. Am I missing smth?

Comment: Still got this bug in 2021 https://codepen.io/dshung1997/pen/LYxvXNy

Comment: Why it doesn't work for width the same way?

Answer (score 271):

Add `height: 1px` to parent container. Works in Chrome, FF, Safari.

Comment: Doing this doesn't resolve the issue, effectively you're overriding the min-height:100% setting which achieves nothing that couldn't be achieved with height:100% which isn't what the OP wants

Comment: `height: 1px` should be on parent and `min-height: 100%` on child. How can one override another?

Comment: please demo this, the parent #containment currently has a min-height of 100px, adding height 1px to this will override the min-height it just wont work, taking the min-height out and using height:1px will also not work

Comment: @styler adding `height: 1px;` will not override the min-height. Quite the opposite. This is the best solution here... demo: http://jsbin.com/mosaboyo/1/edit

Comment: See this for why `height: 1px;` works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341821/height100-vs-min-height100

Comment: @jjenzz The problem with this, which I think styler was trying to get at, is that this does not retain the expansion trait of `min-height`. E.g., if there is enough text it will overflow. See http://jsbin.com/vuyapitizo/1/

Comment: This is true @BrianFunt! Unfortunately, this is the exact behaviour I require :S...100% height empty child div but that also grows when the screen shrinks and content overflows..is there a nice way to do that?

Comment: @SleepyProgrammer ptriek's method seems to be the best, although it's not pretty

Comment: This works even if I set the height : 0 :) I guess the check is min-height is avoided if height : auto. In all the other cases min-height is applied.

Comment: I guess that the parent height is calculated only if we add an explicit `height`, but the actual height is the one from the `min-height`

Comment: Quoting Paul's comment below:
"But it doesn't allow the container to grow, which defeats the purpose of using min-height."
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066/child-inside-parent-with-min-height-100-not-inheriting-height#comment66853175_24481020

Comment: This only works some-times, but can cause other issues elsewhere.

Comment: I have no idea how on earth this solution worked for me.. 

Comment: Setting up `height: 1px` won't fire parent element's ResizeObserver.

Answer (score 210):

thought I would share this, as I didnt see this anywhere, and is what I used to fix my solution.

**SOLUTION**: `min-height: inherit;`

I had a parent with a specified min height, and I needed a child to also be that height.

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5); //yellow
}

.child {
  min-height: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5); //blue
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
  color: red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Yellow + Blue = Green :)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way the child now acts as height 100% of the min-height.

I hope some people find this useful :)

Comment: Partially works, but child only inherits the `min-height`. When parents height is bigger, child won't expand.

Comment: It works in the situations which the parent element doesn't resize.

Comment: It only works when the min-height is absolute, not percentage, AFAICS.

Comment: @OguzGelal In my case I used `height: 100%` as that's what I needed.

Answer (score 54):

This was added in a comment by @jackocnr but I missed it. For modern browsers I think this is the best approach.

It makes the inner element fill the whole container if it's too small, but expands the container's height if it's too big.

```
#containment {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#containment-shadow-left {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: best solution ever

Comment: should be top answer

Comment: ^ I agree, best solution

Comment: best solution  ever saw

Comment: You are a gift. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 21):

Although `display: flex;` has been suggested here, consider using `display: grid;` now that it's [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid). By default, the only child of a grid will entirely fill its parent.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; /* Don't forget Safari */
}

#containment {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

#containment-shadow-left {
  background: aqua;
}
```

Comment: I found this to be the most practical solution for my needs

Comment: nice bit of knowledge there - thx for sharing

Answer (score 10):

Kushagra Gour's solution does work (at least in Chrome and IE) and solves the original problem without having to use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`. See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ULEgY1FDCsk8yiRTfOWU

Setting `min-height: 100%; height: 1px;` on the outer div causes its actual height to be at least 100%, as required. It also allows the inner div to correctly inherit the height.

Comment: But it doesn't allow the container to grow, which defeats the purpose of using min-height.

Comment: I needed a wrapper to fill the parent's min-height and height as well. What worked for me was setting min-height to inherit and height to 100%.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the existing answers, there is also viewport units `vh` to use. Simple snippet below. Of course it can be used together with `calc()` as well, e.g. `min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);` when page header and footer have `200px` height together.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.child {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

This usually works for me:

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe this is a bug with browsers. All behave the same way - that is, once you stop specifying explicit heights, min-height is basically a "last step".

It appears to be exactly how the CSS 2.1 spec suggests:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

Therefore, as the `min-height` parent does not have an explicit `height` property set, it defaults to auto.

There are some ways around this possibly by using `display: table-cell`, or newer styles such as flexbox, if that is possible for your targeted audience's browsers. You can also subvert this in certain situations by using the `top` and `bottom` properties on an absolutely positioned inner element, which gives you 100% height without specifying so.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 14/02/2024**

So I've been working on this a couple of time and the next seems like a perfect solution. Minimum of of screen height, no overflows.

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
}

html,
body,
#content1,
#content2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="content1" :class="$style.content">
            <div id="content2">
                <!-- Your content here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here you dont even need height: 100% to grow up divs.

Note that content2 block is optional, just to show how can you propagate 100% height in child blocks.

Also important thing to mention is that this solution makes unusable percentage heights with reference to body. Anyway, this limitation seems logic because you cannot determine the percentage height of unlimited one. If you need to grow element with user display height, `position: absolute` still works perfect.

To grow up to 100% height the child member you should pass `flex-grow: 1` to every parent.

For me this solution is only one that correctly works when I need to force the footer to the end of a page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I just tried this in jsfiddle and it doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 1):

For googlers:

This jquery-workaround makes #containment get a height automatically (by, height: auto), then gets the actual height assigned as a pixel value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    $(function () {

        // workaround for webkit-bug http://stackoverflow.com/a/8468131/348841

        var rz = function () {
            $('#containment')
            .css('height', 'auto')
            .css('height', $('#containment').height() + 'px');
        };

        $(window).resize(function () {
            rz();
        });

        rz();

    })
-->
</script>
```

Comment: Nice workaround, you can just set the min-height of the element, without setting the height to 'auto'. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another JS solution, that is easy and can be used to avoid a non-easy CSS-only or extra markup / hacky solution.

```
function minHeight(elm, percent) {
  var windowHeight = isNaN(window.innerHeight) ? 
                     window.clientHeight : window.innerHeight;
  var height = windowHeight * percent / 100;
  elm.style.minHeight = height + 'px';
}
```

W/ jQuery :

```
function minHeight($elm, percent) {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var height = windowHeight * percent / 100;
  $elm.css('min-height', height + 'px');
}
```

Angular directive :

```
myModule.directive('minHeight', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      var windowHeight = isNaN($window.innerHeight) ? 
               $window.clientHeight : $window.innerHeight;
      var height = windowHeight * attrs.minHeight / 100;
      elm.css('min-height', height + 'px');
    }
  };
}]);
```

To be used like this :

```
<div>
  <!-- height auto here -->
  <div min-height="100">
    <!-- This guy is at least 100% of window height but grows if needed -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the directive solution. That's what I ended up using but I didn't want window height to be the min; rather I wanted to inherit the min-height of the parent so I changed the code to this: var height = elm.parent()[0].offsetHeight;

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this nowadays is to use `display: flex;`. However you might run into an issue when trying to support IE11. According to https://caniuse.com using flexbox :

> IE 11 does not vertically align items correctly when min-height is used

### Internet Explorer compatible solution

The solution is to use `display: table;` on the parent and `display: table-row;` on the child both with `height: 100%;` as a replacement for `min-height: 100%;`.

Most of the solutions listed here use `display:` `table`, `table-row` and/or `table-cell`, but they don't replicate the same behaviour as `min-height: 100%;`, which is:

- Inherit the computed height of the parent (as opposed to inheriting its `height` property);
- Allow the parent's height to exceed its `min-height`;

While using this solution, the behaviour is the same and the property `min-height` is not needed which allows to get around the bug.

#### Explanation

The reason why it works is because, unlike most elements, elements using `display:` `table` and `table-row` will always be as tall as their content. This makes their `height` property behave similarly to `min-height`.

#### Solution in action

```css
html, body {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}

#containment {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
  width: 100%;
}

#containment-shadow-left {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
  background: aqua;
}

#content {
  padding: 15px;
}

#demo {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

#demo-checkbox:checked ~ #demo {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="containment">
  <div id="containment-shadow-left">
    <div id="content">
      <input id="demo-checkbox" type="checkbox">
      <label for="demo-checkbox">Click here for overflow demo</label>
      <div id="demo">This is taller than #containment</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to parent component fixed it for me:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep this subject complete, I found a solution not explored [Here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/681#issuecomment-86023189) using Fixed position.

#### No Overflow

```css
html, body, .wrapper, .parent, .child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  overflow: auto;
  background: gray;
}

.height-50 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 5em;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      
      <div class="height-50"></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### With Overflow

```css
html, body, .wrapper, .parent, .child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  overflow: auto;
  background: gray;
}

.height-150 {
  height: 150%;
  width: 5em;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      
      <div class="height-150"></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but, if someone else is still struggling with this, i found my workaround.
I need the the parent to have a minimum height,and the children (which will contain several image/files previews) must occupy the whole parent, so..

I simply defined a minimum height to the children a let the parent with no height defined, so it can grow along with the children content.

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.children{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="children">
        some content inside
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add `align-self: normal` to the child item.

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining why this works

Answer (score -3):

after trying for ours! chrome understands that I want the child element to be 100% height when I set the display value to inline block. btw setting float will causing it.

```
display:inline-block
```

update

this is not working. the solution is to get the parentnode offsetheight and use it at the and of the page with javascript.

```
<script>
    SomedivElement = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    SomedivElement.style.height = String(nvleft.parentNode.offsetHeight) + 'px';    
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

This is what works for me with percentage-based height and parent still growing according to children height.
Works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.child {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
```