# How to set 100% height of a parent div with absolutely positioned children (not a duplicate)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, css-position

Suppose an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body  { height:100%; width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
        body        { overflow:scroll; }
        #wrapper    { background:#5f9ea0; width:500px; height:100%; min-height:100%; margin:0 auto; overflow:auto; }
        #content    { background:#336699; width:400px; height:100%; min-height:100%; margin:0 auto; overflow-x:hidden; position:relative;}
        #info-block { background:#d2691e; width:300px; left:20px; position:absolute; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="info-block">Info..<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>...End</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

There's couple of problems with this example:

1. It puts scrollbars into the wrong place `#content` instead of `body`.
2. The `body`, `#wrapper` nor `#content` get a proper height calculated. Expected is `522px` instead of `227px`. (screenshot below).

[image: Height of actual content is 522px]
[image: Height calculated is 227px, which is wrong]

So the actual problem is I need the page to get the height of the content of the `#info-block` element. Tried may different setting, all fail.

The one solution that works - is using jQuery and comparing the height of the `#info-block` against the height of the `body`, and apply it recursively to the `body`, `#wrapper` and `#content`. But this is just wrong. Looking for CSS only solution.

And, I can't get rid of `position:absolute` property of `#info-block` element, because it's a part of interactive horizontal accordion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the layout, meaning their height/width will not affect other element's position/dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked in another Stackoverflow thread, I will link the thread for your viewing.

[child inside parent with min-height 100% not inheriting height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066/child-inside-parent-with-min-height-100-not-inheriting-height)

It seem's that you cant inherit height in Chrome/Safari/Firefox with min-height. Maybe that is the issue? There is the jQuery problem solve in the thread, as well as someone reporting that display: block; should solve the issue.

Have a look!

Comment: Thanks. Did read it. But my problem is opposed: my parent is not inheriting the child's height.