# parent div with absolutely positioned child divs refuses to be 100% height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a 100% height div with absolutely positioned divs inside it. For whatever reason when I add the child divs, the height of the parent div shrinks to the static content size.

To clarify, I do *not* want the absolutely positioned elements to be full-height. Just the containing div.

I have (simplified) markup as follows:

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="dashboard">
      Some text
      <div class="widget"></div>
      <div class="widget"></div>
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

And the styling:

```
#content {
  min-height: 100%;
}
#dashboard {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.widget {
  height: 50px; /* arbitrary */
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I have put `#content` and `#dashboard` as min-height 100% and height 100% and that works. If I comment out the absolutely positioned divs, both are the full height of the screen.

But when I add the `.widget`s, `#content` is still full height (good) but `#dashboard` becomes only the height of 'some text'. For whatever reason, *adding absolutely positioned content to `#dashboard` changes its height.*

**Note (edit)**

> I don't want `#content` to be 100% height because it needs to grow
>   with content on other pages. I *only* want #dashboard to be exactly 100%
>   height.

jQuery works, but I'd like to do it with css only

```
$("#dashboard").height( $("#content").height() );
```

Also I tried changing the type of display to block or inline for `#content` and setting -moz-box-sizing to default because I read it can break min-height for Firefox.

Any idea how to fix this?

---

Similar but not the same: [How to set 100% height of a parent div with absolutely positioned children (not a duplicate)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460054/how-to-set-100-height-of-a-parent-div-with-absolutely-positioned-children-not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height):

> A percentage value for [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) property is calculated with
>   respect to the **height** of the generated box's containing block.
>   If the `height` of the containing block is not specified **explicitly** (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated as **0**.

Hence, you'll need to specify the `height` of the `#content` element explicitly to get `min-height` property of `#dashboard` element to work.

Thus, try using `height` property for `#content` instead of `min-height`:

```css
#content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a **[jsDiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/RZqDE/30/)**.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
  height: 100%;
}
#dashboard {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.widget {
  height: 50px; /* arbitrary */
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}​
```

```html
<div id="content">
   <div id="dashboard">
      Some text
      <div class="widget"></div>
      <div class="widget"></div>
      ...
   </div>
</div>​
```

**UPDATE**

> I don't want `#content` to be full-size at all times.

Then, you'll need to use a fixed height for the `#content`:

```css
#content {
  height: 200px;  /* or whatever you want */
}

#dashboard {
  height: 100%;   /* or inherit */;
}
```

Else, you should use JavaScript to calculate the needed height and apply that to the `#dashboard` element.

Comment: I don't want #content to be full-size at all times. I want it to extend indefinitely on other pages...

Comment: So why did you use `min-height` ??
however, you can use any percentages or pixels you want.

Comment: I want it to take up the whole screen or extend. Thats what min-height is for, no?

Comment: Let me know what exactly you mean.

Comment: Edited question. Your solution would work, but #content is a centered content div with a background in the middle of the page, so I can't have overflowing content, and I can't have it scroll or I'd have a scrollbar in the middle of the page!

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the layout. The parent element has no idea how big child items are.

You need to set the height of the parent manually, or use JS to calculate the size of the child elements and apply accordingly.

Also, 100% height elements need their parent elements to be 100% height as well:

```
body, html { height:100% }
```

Comment: Parent (#dashboard) height is specified at 100%

Comment: +1 the height at 100% only takes up 100% of its parent element which in this case is the body, html :) - http://jsfiddle.net/mcAXP/

Comment: `#content` is set to min-height: 100%, but according to @Hashem, setting that to `height: 100%` works. -- Apparently this is not a solution for OP though.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to have a min-height of 100% (min 100%, expand when there is more content) for #content, use min-height together with `height: auto`:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Furthermore, if i understand your question correctly, you could simply use `position: absolute` together with `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;` to have exactly a height of 100% for #dashboard. Add `position: relative` to #content if the height of #dashboard should be relative to #content.

Comment: Not quite, #content floats and is under another div. Thanks for the `auto` tip!

Answer (score 0):

Absolute elements are taken out of the flow.
If they are out of the flow, they do not add height to their parent.

Comment: Parent (`#dashboard`) height is specified at 100%

Comment: Because the OP does not seem unaware that absolute positioning takes elements out of the flow. (I.e. That is not the issue here.)

Comment: Since OP did not know how to use the height property I assumed a clarification of the absolute positioning was in place.
Since I cannot comment, because of my low reputation, I answered.
My bad.
Should I delete it?

Comment: _Since OP did not know how to use the height property_ I didn't get that impression. He said that `height: 100%` worked as long as the child DIVs were not `position: absolute`. Which I verified in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/4zwyW/. (Change `#content` `min-height` to `height` and see it work.)

Comment: If you'll edit your answer, though I will remove the downvote. (Tried already, but is locked in till you edit)

Comment: "He said that height: 100% worked as long as the child DIVs were not position: absolute."
And this was why I explained how absolute positioning works.

Comment: `height: 100%` should make the element 100% regardless of the positioning of the child elements. (Assuming parent elements allow for it)