# CSS Height working but min-height doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a strange rather weird problem. The problem is a small one that is I want to set min-height to 100% that is the content of the page should span whole screen of he user and if possible the page should extend down if content exceeds 100%.  A simple way would be to set min-height:100% and to set height:auto that is exactly what I want but regardless of how many times I try it the problem remains there.

I am using height auto and min-height:100% on all the elements but it doesn't work. If I remove min-height to include only height:100% then it works like a charm but then when the content is larger it overflows whole footer.

Please help me here is css:

```
html, body, container, row, col-lg-3, col-lg-9 {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
 }
 .container {
     max-width: 1170px;
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
 }
 .col-lg-3 {
     min-height:100%;
     height:100%;
 }
 .col-lg-9 {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

Here is the page showing the problem : 
http://contestlancer.com/ai/GP/

Comment: Can u show us ur HTML..

Comment: @Kaushik I am using columns in twitter bootstrap I have posted the link in the post. Putting code here will take too much space please take a look

Comment: So u want left side menu contents with blue background to cover the whole page??

Comment: @Kaushik yes the center content must also cover whole page. In short the whole content must cover whole page

Comment: u said if u remove min-height and set only height then it will work but it will overflow the footer right?? Y dont you try adding z-index to the footer so that it will always remain on the top of anything..? Did u try it...??

Comment: @Kaushik even if it remains at top it will overlap  other content don't want to do that way

Comment: Ok.. Have you tried setting css overflow property for the.. so that extra contents whatever appears on the div will be displayed inside the div with a scroll bar..

Comment: If you don't want the scroll effect, then you could always add overflow:hidden;, and it will hide anything that goes below the 100%

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes this is a pain but that's how it works. Height can be inherited from positioned parents but not when these have a `min-height` property.

Children of elements that have a `min-height` set to `100%` cannot inherit their parent's height via percentage...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468131/1491212

CSS2.1 specs :

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto'.

Use `position: relative; height: 100%` on containers to work around the problem, and add `min-height: 100%;` to the deepest child.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't really know what do you mean? So I keep the css as it is but add position relative to every container?

Comment: That doesnt work bro... position will not effect here to the div

Comment: @AhmarAli yes that's what I mean but I don't have an all-made answer for you... What I usually do is set min-height: 100% on the deepest children and height: 100%; position: relative; on containers