# Set height relative to parents parent but stretch parent

Tags: html, css, dom

This HTML structure has a `div#page`, in which the current page content will be loaded via Ajax. The content always consists of `section` tags, which can have a dynamic height (in percent relative to the browser) or a static height (in pixels).

The height of `div#page` should adjust, so that the `footer` will follow immediately after the last `div#page > section`.

To be able to set a value in percent for the `div#page > section` tags however, I gave `div#page` a height of 100%. Therefore, it's DOM height won't stretch.

If the `footer` tag was inside `div#page`, it would work. This is not a good solution for me, because the footer would be overwritten by the dynamicaly loaded page content.

Is there some magic CSS solution to stretch the `div#page` properly?

```css
body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#outer { background: red; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#page { height: 100%; }

#page > section { background: #666; width: 100%; }
#page > section:nth-of-type(2n) { background: #333; }
#page > section:nth-of-type(1) { height: 100%; }
#page > section:nth-of-type(2) { height: 160px; }
#page > section:nth-of-type(3) { height: 220px; }
#page > section:nth-of-type(4) { height: 120px; }

footer { background: green; height: 160px; }
```

```html
<div id="outer">

    <!-- The current page content will be loaded into this div. -->
    <div id="page">
      <section>Full height.</section>
      <section>Static height 1.</section>
      <section>Static height 2.</section>
      <section>Static height 3.</section>
    </div>

    <!-- The footer is static and therefore not inside of the #page div. -->
    <footer>
      Immediately after static height 3.
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: @maioman You can't really use relative height with a min-height parent. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969022/css-height-working-but-min-height-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drop the height for the `#page` div and set the first `section` to `100vh` I guess it will work as you want, though with newer browsers only, that support the "viewport" unit `vh`.

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

```css
  body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  #outer { background: red; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
  #page { }

  #page > section { background: #666; width: 100%; }
  #page > section:nth-of-type(2n) { background: #333; }
  #page > section:nth-of-type(1) { height: 100vh; }
  #page > section:nth-of-type(2) { height: 160px; }
  #page > section:nth-of-type(3) { height: 220px; }
  #page > section:nth-of-type(4) { height: 120px; }

  footer { background: green; height: 160px; }
```

```html
<div id="outer">

    <!-- The current page content will be loaded into this div. -->
    <div id="page">
      <section>Full height.</section>
      <section>Static height 1.</section>
      <section>Static height 2.</section>
      <section>Static height 3.</section>
    </div>

    <!-- The footer is static and therefore not inside of the #page div. -->
    <footer>
      Immediately after static height 3.
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i tried to resolve this way by changing the position of the **outer** div

```css
body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  #outer { background: red; position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto; }
  #page { height: 100%; }

  #page > section { background: #666; width: 100%; }
  #page > section:nth-of-type(2n) { background: #333; }
  #page > section:nth-of-type(1) { height: 100%;background: red; }
  #page > section:nth-of-type(2) { height: 160px;background: yellow; }
  #page > section:nth-of-type(3) { height: 220px;background: aqua; }
  #page > section:nth-of-type(4) { height: 120px;background: darkblue; }

  footer { background: green; height: 160px; }
```

i have included the working demo code so that you can check out put is it as you expect or not ..

**[Demo Code you can check out](https://jsfiddle.net/kt91pmg6/)**

Comment: @ChristophBühler please check out the answer is it valid or not.?

Comment: The red container should be 100% of the page height. It's not at the moment.