# Flexbox: Difference min-height vs. height on flex element?

Tags: css, flexbox, height

I would like a `flex-element` with a min-height of 100%. 
There is a child element always at the bottom. 
If the content in the first flex child is longer than the screen the site should be normal scrollable.

[Here](https://codepen.io/Ranuss/pen/XaLypj) is a pen I made.

Why is it working with height but not min-height?

```css
height: 100%; // works

min-height: 100%; // doesn't works
```

Comment: This question should be edited and references to Flexbox should be removed, since it has nothing to do with Flexbox

Answer (score 1):

As answered here: [CSS Height working but min-height doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969022/css-height-working-but-min-height-doesnt-work)

> Height can be inherited from positioned parents but not when these have a min-height property.

Which means that `.flexbox` doesn't inherit height from wrapper because `.wrapper` has min-height set. When you set `height` to `.wrapper`, `.flebox` and with it `.grower` can figure out what 100% actually means, and then they grow to fit the screen.

Note: I would say position part of the linked answer is not correct, but the quoted part is.

Answer (score 0):

min-height : Height of the element or css class in question should not be less than specified value, even if height is less that specified value of min-height. It does not specify what the height is going to be, it specifies that it cannot be smaller than its value.

So, if height is 200px, max-height is 230px, min-height is 250px, height of the page component will be 250px. Between height and max-height, max-height can override height.

So, if I change your wrapper class to as shown below, it's height will remain 80%.

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  min-height: 80%;
  height:50px;
}
```