# I don't understand "height: 100vh" over "min-height: 100vh"

Tags: css, flexbox

So this is my layout:

```
<div style="display: flex; min-height:100vh">
  <div>Sidebar</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 2">All my views</div> // Container of the main content of my app
</div>
```

The result is this:

[image]

The sidebar is stuck to the left and the main content is taking most of the space, perfect.

Inside the container of my app, let's say I wan't a login component:

```
<div style="display: flex; min-height:100vh">
  <div>Sidebar</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 2">
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height:100%">
      My login component
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I center it with Flexbox and by setting a `height: 100%`. Since the parent container is itself stretching the height fixed by its parent, it works.

**Now the problem:**

In mobile, the sidebar is on the top of the page. Therefore, I'm adding to the root container a `flex-direction: column` to it, like that:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height:100vh">
  <div>Sidebar</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 2">All my views</div> // Container of the main content of my app
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

See what's wrong? Why is not centered like it was on desktop?

That's because the login div, the one nested into the content container that has a `flex-grow: 2` is not filling up the entire height anymore:

[image]

Even though the container is still stretching and the div has a `height: 100%` ?? Why this behavior??

Well after HOURS of trying to understand what was going on, I tried using `height: 100vh` instead of `min-height: 100vh` on the root container and it freaking works.

[image]

Why the hell does it work now? `min-height` and `height` have the same effect, they set specific height for the root container. I tried both and the result on my desktop view is the same, it's only on mobile viewport, when my root container has a `flex-direction: column`, that the login component doesn't fill up the height anymore.

Btw I don't want to use `height: 100vh`! What if the content is higher than 100vh? I don't want an ugly overflow, that's why I always use `min-height`. I'm stuck, how can I fix that?

Comment: So you need the left area to fill the height of the screen?

Comment: I don't investigate a lot for your problem, but you can try something like position:absolute and z-index property.

Comment: Avoiding this kind of problem is exactly the sort of reason most of us use 'vh' units, so this does seem like really weird behavior. Perhaps explicitly setting the flex-basis on the nested login component would allow you to avoid the use of height: 100vh; on the parent? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Height working but min-height doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969022/css-height-working-but-min-height-doesnt-work)