# Safari height 100% element inside a max-height element

Tags: safari, css

I'm trying to figure out why Safari won't read the max-height attribute of its parent as the height. Both Chrome and Firefox will read it correctly, but Safari seems to ignore the parent's max-height and instead grabs the page's full height.

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bwheZ/)

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
}
div span {
    background: #f0f;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

I'm using Safari 6.0.5 on OSX 10.8.5.

Comment: It seems like [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26559) is responsible. Here's also an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8468131/1456376) about it. The only solution that worked for me was adding `div { position: absolute; }`, [try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nbVXN/).

Comment: @insertusernamehere Perfect. I still hate safari ;) if you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This issue happens due to a reported bug in Webkit:

> [Bug 26559 - When a block's height is determined by min-height/max-height, children with percentage heights are sized incorrectly](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26559)

This seems to be fixed for Chrome by now, but not for Safari.

The only non-JavaScript workaround that worked for me, is using an absolute positioning on the parent element:

```
div {     
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/nbVXN/)

Comment: @insertusernamehere, but what about case you want to build two divs one after the second? take your HTML and copy it, then put the copied div after the orginal. can you see the copy?...

Answer (score 8):

Similar problem appears on Safari if parent element uses `flexbox` properties - container won't take 100% of the height.
Another solution (besides `position: absolute;`) would be to use `vh` (viewport height) units:

```
div {
 height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I spent hours looking for this solution... worked like a charm! The absolute positioning didn't work, but setting the height on the div immediately inside of the div with `display: flex` worked!

Comment: @sergey-dubovik  This was a lifesaver! Thanks!