# my page loads half in ios but full in android

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My page is loading full in android devices but it's loading half in iOS,
earlier it was working fine but somehow I got this problem, I'm sharing the screenshot here.It's coming half in iOS but full in Android.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some code in order to help you here?

Comment: From my experience, Safari is not a big fan of `height: 100%` so I might recommand to look in such direction. There is not enough details to help, may be try isolating this issue in a short codepen you could share and we could work on .

Comment: Sounds a lot like this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119910/safari-height-100-element-inside-a-max-height-element