# max-height not working properly in Safari

Tags: html, css, accordion

I'm trying to create responsive accordion using the below code:

```
    <div class="tabs specs">
   <div class="tab">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chck1">
      <label class="tab-label" for="chck1">GIFT DETAILS</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Simple and Elegant Love Letter/Card Message Included Inside Standard Gift Box.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tab">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chck2">
      <label class="tab-label" for="chck2">SHIPPING TIME</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Simple and Elegant Love Letter/Card Message Included Inside Standard Gift Box.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<style>
.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
.tab {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tab-label {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  background: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333333;
  /* Icon */
}
.tab-label:hover {
  background: white;
}
.tab-label::after {
  content: "\276F";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
} 
.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #333333;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}
input:checked + .tab-label {
  background: white;
}
input:checked + .tab-label::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}
input:checked ~ .tab-content {
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding: 1em;
}
.specs input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
</style>
```

While the accordion is working on Safari (both mobile and desktop) there was an error where the content was revealed even before I clicked on the tab itself.

I have tried to use max-height: auto but it didn't work. Could someone let me know what I was doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119910/safari-height-100-element-inside-a-max-height-element have you tried any of these solutions?

Comment: @SigurdMazanti Yes I did, none of them are working for me. With the position:absolute it evens make the text overlapping each other

Comment: Why did you try `max-height: auto`? That doesn't [seem to be a valid value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height#formal_syntax).  You should make a runnable example, it's hard to tell what your problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `max-height` you can use `height` and `opacity` to animate the accordion. This also works in Safari on MacOS and iOS. To make the "jump" disappear after collapsing, I've also removed the margin of the paragraph. I've adjusted:

```css
.tab-content {
  /* removed: max-height: 0; */
  /* new */
  height: 0; 
  opacity: 0;

  /* ... */
}

/* new */
.tab-content p {
  margin: 0; 
}

input:checked ~ .tab-content {
  /* new */
  height: auto; 
  opacity: 1;
  /* removed: max-height: 100vh; */
  
  /* ... */ 
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coreuter/x1aem0ro/) with the complete code.