# Make container div fills all layout with sticky footer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I creating an new layout for a personal website.

I'm using *Twitter Bootstrap 3*, and my initial layout was made using as exemple
the "Bootstrap with sticky footer" sample (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/)

This is my html:

```
<body>
    <!-- Wrap all page content here -->
    <div id="wrap">
        <!-- Begin page navigation -->
        <nav id="nav-container" class="navbar navbar-default container" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Here I put a very normal Bootstrap 3 navbar -->
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Begin page content -->
        <div id="main-container" class="container">
            <!-- All my content goes here! -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Begin page footer -->
    <footer id="footer" class="container">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

The Sticky Footer CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -100px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 100px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
  height: 100px;
}
```

And the custom style for my layout:

```
body {
    /* Body's background will be grey */
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
#main-container {
    /* A box where I'll put the content will be white */
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#wrap {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#main-container {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This code generate this layout:

[image: LayoutNow]

But, as you can see, the `div #main-container` don't grow 'till the end of the layout.
The `div` keep with the height of his content.

What I want is that this div always fills the entire page, like this:

[image: LayoutThen]

Many solutions on internet said me to fix `min-height` to some tested value, but this way
I'll not be able to keep my website responsive (it's very important to me keep my layout
always responsive, that's the main reason I use Bootstrap 3).

Other solution goes to calculate the div height with javascript. Personally I don't like
this solution. I whish I could solve this only by using CSS.

Someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can create the illusion of #main-container grow till the end by setting #wrap's background-color the same value as #main-container's.

Comment: Yeah I have same problem over and over again but I believe its not possible to do just yet at least not with CSS and HTML

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for the help! @AntonisGrigoriadis, your solution is perfect! All I had to do was set my `#wrap` to have the same width as `#main-container` and put the background color.

Comment: I actually can't believe that setting `#main-container` min-height won't work... someone knows the reason for that?

Comment: Great idea @AntonisGrigoriadis thanks! My main container div had a semi transparent background so I had to use a transparent png background image for the parent div that matched the width and position of the main container. This obviously needs tweaking at smaller screen widths as the background image will not always adapt with the rest of the layout.

Comment: Glad that helped you @user1794295. vinigarcia87 I think that `min-height` doesn't work due to a reported bug. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066/ . By the way is my answer an acceptable solution to your problem? Should I post it as an answer for future readers to be helped?

Comment: Yes, @AntonisGrigoriadis! Post your answer so I can accept it. Put this bug info too! Most important to me, I guess, is know why this not work the way I think it should... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `min-height` doesn't work due to a reported bug. See this: [stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066).

An easy way to create the illusion that #main-container grows till the end, is to set #wrap's background-color the same value as #main-container's.

Comment: As they pointed out in the link you gave, this is not a bug, this is exactly the way it is suppsed to work. Percentage heights are ignored when parent height is not strictly defined. 100% of auto gives you auto :) As a side note, I found a way to get a real fullheight container instead of faking it with background color. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you are working on percentage, your site will be responsive. So using 
min-height:100% does solve your problem which is just CSS. And if you don't want Javascript involved here, that is the way to go.

See the **[JS Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7XB5/1/)**. Your container is filling the entire page.

```
#main-container {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help! unfortunately, my `#main-container` already have `min-height: 100%;` set, but it didn't work. :/

Comment: @vinigarcia87 Try changing the height on `#wrap` to `height: 100%;`. Worked for me!

Comment: @Morven You may want to mention that you need to specify height as `100%` instead of `auto`. Then, I think this is the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have sticky footer AND fullheight #main-container, you have to modify your structure. First, let me explain why you can't solve this with the sticky-footer method you're using right now:
Setting #main-container's height:100% or min-height:100% won't work because you can't use percentage height with a parent whose height is not strictly defined. Note that in the currently accepted answer this is considered a bug but it is not, it's just the way it is supposed to work. In your example #wrap's height is set to auto, so #main-container height just ignores the 100% and fallsback to auto.

To have both sticky footer and REAL fullheight #main-container (instead of faking with background) you have to use `display:table` and `display:table-row`. This works because when you use `display:table`, `height:100%` works just as your regular `min-height:100%` and the `display:table-row`s inside will always stretch to use all the vertical space available.
NOTE: this is different from using html tables, because in this case you don't need to bloat your markup with non-semantic tags, as you'll see in the following example.
Here's the example HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="maincontainer" class="astable">
            <div id="header" class="astablerow">
                header
            </div>
            <div id="middlecontainer" class="astablerow">
                content
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="astablerow">
                footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
.astable{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
.astablerow{
    display: table-row;
}
#header{
    height:30px;
    background-color:#00ff00;
}
#footer{
    height:30px;
    background-color:#0000ff;
}
#middlecontainer{
   background-color:#ff0000;
}
```