# Why does height of body not match height of html?

Tags: html, css

This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body { min-height: 100%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Chrome, Firefox, and Safari inspectors all show the html element with height equal to the browser window as should be the case, but the body element with height 0. Setting the height (not just min-height) of the body element to 100% doesn't help. The body element should have height equal to 100% of its parent element, the html element, which has height equal to the window. So why doesn't it?

Comment: Good question regarding min-height not working on the body element. Although adding `height:100%` actually does work, try it: http://jsfiddle.net/ND74j/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make body have 100% of the browser height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)

Answer (score 4):

Try restricting its height to always only be 100% using `height` and `min-height`, like so:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/D4qvG/4/)**

Another possible way is to give the parent (in this case, the `html` tag) a height of 100%, and then give the child (`body` tag) the `min-height`, like so:

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/D4qvG/3/)**

Here is a similar question to yours that can answer some more indepth questions - [Make body have 100% of the browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)

Comment: Any idea why `min-height` alone doesn't work for the body element? Also, if you use `height:100%` I don't think you need `min-height:100%`.

Comment: It seems to be a Webkit bug, unless they are intentionally doing it. I will keep looking around for a proper answer to your question. Although, as you can see from this fiddle, using `div`s works perfectly. So it is definitely a problem just with the `body` and `html` tags - http://jsfiddle.net/S3MxC/

Answer (score 2):

The reason this does not work is percentage based `height` vales require that the `height` be set on the parent element (except for the `html` node, which is based off the viewport). While the browser will always render the `html` node as the full browser, you actually need to set the `height` in CSS for the `body` to base the percentage off of. I believe what you are looking for is the following.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QPFPQ/)

This is a cleaner solution to setting both `body` and `html` to `height: 100%;` as the body will commonly be larger than 100% of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working .Add bgcolor to your body element and see if it is 100%. I tried following code which is working -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body { min-height: 100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#00CC33">
<div>HELLO</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As to why `min-height` is not working, see: [child inside parent with min-height 100% not inheriting height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066/child-inside-parent-with-min-height-100-not-inheriting-height?lq=1)

Also note, using `body,html { height: 100% }` instead, works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/ND74j/

Answer (score 0):

Restricting the `height` to always be the height of its parent element will work but you need to add a light CSS reset:

```
html, body{
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

For a full CSS reset see [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 0):

This is something I recently came across and was able to resolve with this:

```
body {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}


// this class is a div containing all your page's content

.body {
    width: 1400px; // arbitrary number
    margin: auto;
}
```