# Div doesnt fill parent

Tags: css

Trival case is working

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
}
.container{
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
}
.element{
    background: gray;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5zjkcqkL/

Gray element has same height as his green parent

Here is my "minimal working sample"

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>

    <div id="content">        
        <div class="text-background">
            Some content text   
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">        
        Footer            
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: black;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#content {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 172px; /* Height of the footer element */
    background: green;
}

#footer {
    border-top: 2px #999 solid;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:black;
}

#header{
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.text-background {
    background: gray;    
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;   
    width:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mrxfbszz/

Why gray div doesnt fill its green parent by height?

Comment: Change the `min-height` for content and wrapper to `height`.

Comment: Add `height: 100%;` to your `#wrapper` and your `#content`. Also add it to your `body`. That seemed to work from my end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [child inside parent with min-height 100% not inheriting height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066/child-inside-parent-with-min-height-100-not-inheriting-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `padding-bottom: 172px;` to `height: 172px;`

```
#content {
    height: 172px;
    background: green;
}
```

See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrxfbszz/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change the height on your wrapper and #content to 100%