# height: 100vh; and overflow "content" on smaller screens

Tags: css

I have a `height: 100vh;` but I have a lot of content, which overflows into another "vh" on smaller screens, how do I deal w/ the overflow, on smaller screens?

Comment: What is exactly the problem and what is the desired behavior? A [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Comment: On a small screen the 'height: 100vh;' flows into the next 'height: 100vh;' so it becomes jumbled and un-readable.

Comment: FYI beware of iOS and viewport units http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple elements with `height: 100vh`, and the problem is that their content may overflow them.

In that case, you can

- Use the `overflow` property to handle overflow correctly.

  For example `overflow: auto` will add scrollbars only when necessary.

  ```css
  html,body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  section {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    background: yellow;
  }
  section + section {
    background: lime;
  }
  div {
    height: 150vh;
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-left: 1px dotted;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <section>
    Start<div></div>End
  </section>
  <section>
    Start<br />End
  </section>
  ```
- Use `min-height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100vh`

  This way, if the content is taller, the element will grow to avoid overflow.

  ```css
  html,body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: yellow;
  }
  section + section {
    background: lime;
  }
  div {
    height: 150vh;
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-left: 1px dotted;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <section>
    Start<div></div>End
  </section>
  <section>
    Start.<br />End
  </section>
  ```

Comment: @Oriol Amazing! Use `min-height: 100vh` works great! Thank you!

Comment: `min-height: 100vh` works well until you need a child item to take 100% of that container's height. Then you encounter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066/child-inside-parent-with-min-height-100-not-inheriting-height

Comment: You are my hero.

Answer (score 4):

Please try `overflow: auto;` in the style of the container.

[Sample code](http://codepen.io/YaserAliPeedikakkal/pen/QyMEjO)