# Make child having x% of parent's height set by min-height

Tags: html, css, height

***My question isn't duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css), because in my case I use `min-height` attribute, which works slightly different than common `height`.***

My issue is more advanced version of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066/child-inside-parent-with-min-height-100-not-inheriting-height) and concerns counterintuitive CSS behavior of `min-height` attribute. I'd like to set my child's height to 80% of parent's height set by `min-height` attribute. As shown below, we can set 100% of parent's height by inheriting `min-height` value, but I cannot do this for smaller percentage. Of course I don't like to set `100px` for my child explicitly.

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.child {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#c1 {
  min-height: inherit; /* =100% of parent's height*/
}
#c2 {
  min-height: 80%; /* doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div id='c1' class='child'></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='parent'>
  <div id='c2' class='child'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `position: relative` to parent and `position: absolute` to child

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

#c1 {
  min-height: inherit;
  /* =100% of parent's height*/
}

#c2 {
  min-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div id='c1' class='child'></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='parent'>
  <div id='c2' class='child'></div>
</div>
```