# Why does height: 100% make the height smaller in this example?

Tags: css, height

I came across this issue today and can't make sense of why the `block1` element is less height than `block2` after specifying `height: 100%` in `block1`. Why does it behave this way?

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/mjacobson7/pen/wvgXjQM)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block1">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>World</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>World</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.block1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Here is the answer about this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066/child-inside-parent-with-min-height-100-not-inheriting-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent div `container` doesn't have a fixed height. Therefore, the height is based on the content, it takes 100% of the inner content (= `height: auto`). I added a fixed height to the codepen and you can see that, now, the div takes 100% of the container height.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/lachips/pen/wvgXXvz)