# flexbox with min-height that doesn't stretch with content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

https://jsfiddle.net/u7fkjrvy/17/

I have a scrollable container with flex column.
Each children has "min-height: 100%" (I want each div to fit the height of the screen). The problem is, when the content of the children is bigger than 100%, the children will not stretch to fit the content inside. I don't understand why because it should be just a minimum as it's not "height" parameter ?

To summarize :  I want a div with `min-height:100vh` to also stretch with his content

**HTML and CSS**

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:scroll;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:scroll;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue
}

section{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding:10px
}

.content{
  height: 120vh;
  background-color:black;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<container>
  <section>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section></section>
</container>
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: If I understand correctly, in your example you don't want to see yellow anymore is it right ? If yes, simply remove the padding: 10px you added to your section

Comment: Not exactly, I want the yellow div to expand to fit the black div height (wich is more than 100vh, the min-height of the yellow div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to stop the flex-items shrinking to fit in the container space.

i.e. add `flex-shrink: 0`.

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:scroll;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:scroll;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue
}

section{
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding:10px
}

.content{
  height: 120vh;
  background-color:black;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<container>
  <section>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section></section>
</container>
```

Comment: It was that simple... Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your min height on your section and it will work as shown here

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:scroll;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:scroll;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue
}

section{
  background-color: yellow;
  padding:10px;
}

.content{
  height: 1200vh;
  background-color:black;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<container>
  <section>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section></section>
</container>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I'd like to keep the min-height on my sections so that it's at least the height of the screen, and if the content of the section is taller than this, I'd like it to stretch to fit the content

Comment: You might wanna take a look at this then, there are multiple solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066/child-inside-parent-with-min-height-100-not-inheriting-height<

Comment: I don't think it's the same problem… I want a div with `min-height:100vh` to also stretch with his content

Comment: Okok, I'm just sayin it's not because a solution apply to a problem that it doesn't apply to another :D Have a great day I hope you'll find the answer you're looking for