# height:100% not giving full parent height

Tags: html, css

While i was working on a website with one-page scrollable layout, i came across this:

when giving `height:100%` to an element inside a `min-height:100%` parent, it doesnt actually go full height.

Can someone explain this behaviour? In css there are obviously many ways to reach the same result, but understanding the underlying reasons will help me and anyone with a similar question greatly.

I'll include this jsfiddle to illustrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/kNwhu/1/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's a good explanation of why you're seeing what you're seeing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341821/height100-vs-min-height100

Comment: Thank you, LuFuMa, that is most helpful information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inside `section` because you specify a `min-height` but not the `height`
try to insert `height:100%` to section like this:

```
section{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color: #cc333f;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kNwhu/2/)