# Overflow-y with flex-end - Why no scrollbar?

Tags: css, flexbox, scrollbar

Can someone please explain for me why the ".child" elements exceed their parent but no overflow-y scroll bar appears?  Have a look at the Pen.  The container on the left shows the parent with 3 child items.  The container on the right shows the parent with 6 items which exceed the parent.

The goal is to have all ".child" items pushed to the bottom of their ".parent" container and if i add more it will expand from the bottom to top until it reaches the limit of the parent, at which point the scroll bar appears.  This would be similar behavior to a chatbox messenger window.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZdKBZ)

```css
.outside {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid green;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.child {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside" style="float:left; margin-right:10px">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 3
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="outside">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 3
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 4
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 5
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `min-height: 100%` on the `.parent` instead of `height: 100%`:

```css
.outside {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid green;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parent {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.child {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside" style="float:left; margin-right:10px">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 3
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="outside">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 3
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 4
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 5
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may also want to add `overflow-x: hidden` to the `.outside` if you don't want to see the horizontal scrollbar. Alternately, you could use `width:100%` on the parent.

```css
.outside {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid green;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.parent {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.child {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside" style="float:left; margin-right:10px">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 3
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="outside">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 3
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 4
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 5
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Align to the bottom 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answer worked great.  Thx.  Now can u explain the difference between height:100% and min-height:100% for this situation? To me they amount to exactly the same statement.  I'm reading some articles and it still doesnt make any sense.

Comment: @user2522885 This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2341935/8828658

Comment: Is it possible to rework things so that overflow is removed from the "outside" and is applied directly onto the "parent" ?